# Plotting values on map with geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, geopandas

I have these data from the years 1991-2020 and for five countries.

```
Date          Temperature    Units  Year Month Statistics Country CODE
                                                             
Jan 2020        -26.2  Celsius  1991   Jan    Average  Canada  CAN
Feb 2020        -21.0  Celsius  1991   Feb    Average  Canada  CAN
Mar 2020        -18.2  Celsius  1991   Mar    Average  Canada  CAN
Apr 2020         -8.6  Celsius  1991   Apr    Average  Canada  CAN
May 2020          0.8  Celsius  1991   May    Average  Canada  CAN
```

m2020

```
 pop_est      continent    name CODE  ...  Country ISO2   latitude   longitude
0  35623680  North America  Canada  CAN  ...   Canada   CA  56.130366 -106.346771
1  35623680  North America  Canada  CAN  ...   Canada   CA  56.130366 -106.346771
2  35623680  North America  Canada  CAN  ...   Canada   CA  56.130366 -106.346771
3  35623680  North America  Canada  CAN  ...   Canada   CA  56.130366 -106.346771
4  35623680  North America  Canada  CAN  ...   Canada   CA  56.130366 -106.346771
```

In the world map, I am plotting the temperature of each country for the year 2020. I want to create a plot for each month, so I created a loop that goes through each month. When I plot, I do get 12 plots but the values of Temperature do not change throughout the months. Do you know what can be the problem? In my plot I want to see that for example in January Canada shows a blue color indicating -26, and for May it shows a green color indicating 0.8 degrees.

I did this:

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))world.columns=['pop_est', 'continent', 'name', 'CODE', 'gdp_md_est', 'geometry']
    
for i in m2020.groupby(['Month']).Month:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,12))
    world.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgrey')
    m2020.plot(x="longitude", y="latitude", kind="scatter",
                      c='Temperature', colormap="hsv", 
                      ax=ax)
    plt.title(i[0])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try at first inserting the range of min and max temperature variables before the for-loop:

> vmin=m2020["Temperature"].min()

> vmax=m2020["Temperature"].max()

Then modify the third line inside the for-loop:

```
m2020.plot("Temperature",x="longitude", y="latitude", kind="scatter",
                      vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, colormap="hsv",ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar exercise is made here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-python-to-obtain-the-temperature-of-any-place-on-earth-b92aae44b831

When just copy-pasting the code, some errors were raised in my case. I needed to do a bit of debugging, but in the end you can get it working.